# How to find the port from IP address which is of the form 192.168.1.98,193,148

Tags: networking

I am told that one can derive the port number if the IP is of the given form.

How does one do that? My searches didnt lead me anywhere

Edit ==

I am leaving the question containing the term IP address as this is something many people are likely to search for. Technically, from the document linked in the answer

> If
>               this command is used, the argument is the concatenation of a
>               32-bit internet host address and a 16-bit TCP port address.
>               This address information is broken into 8-bit fields and the
>               value of each field is transmitted as a decimal number (in
>               character string representation).  The fields are separated
>               by commas.  A port command would be:
>
> ```
>            PORT h1,h2,h3,h4,p1,p2
>
>         where h1 is the high order 8 bits of the internet host
>         address.
> ```

Comment: IP address and port numbers are separate things and IP address does not contain port number. They are sometimes written together as `192.168.1.1:1234`, but not like you wrote in he question.

Comment: What does `192.168.1.98,193,148` mean? That you have three IP addresses: `192.168.1.98`, `192.168.1.193`, `192.168.1.148`? Or maybe the person who 'told' you this meant that 193 and 148 are port numbers? Either way it's non-standard notation and IPs and ports are completely separate things.

Comment: This is not "an IP address". The stuff before the first comma is an IP address; maybe the two other numbers are the local and remote port numbers, maybe in that order. Usually the remote port number would be much larger, 40000-something.

Comment: @triplee perhaps calling it an IP address is technically incorrect, but the first four numbers happen to be the same as the IP address and many noobs like me, when searching would search for how to find the port from IP address. Anyway, I got the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @alan see my comment above and the answer below.

Comment: @rafalrawicki see my comment above and the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the PORT ftp command.

As seen in the [RFC 959, page 28](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt), those two numbers represents the two bytes of a 16-bit word, as decimal numbers, with the high one first.

The general formula is:

```
(b1 << 8) | b2
```

Applied to your specific case:

```
(193 << 8) | 148 = 49 556
```